# dynamically changing id attribute of any tag for countless times

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```js
$("#add_driver").click(function() {
  $("#add_driver_section").replaceWith("<div class='wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100' ><span class='label-input100'>Gender</span><div class='contact100-form-radio m-t-15'> <input class='input-radio100' id='radio1' type='radio' name='type- product[]' value='male' checked='checked' > <label class='label-radio100' for='radio1'> Male </label></div><div class='contact100-form-radio'> <input class='input-radio100' id='radio2' type='radio' name='type-product[]' value='female'> <label class='label-radio100' for='radio2'> Female </label> </div></div>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
  <span class="label-input100">Gender</span>
  <div class="contact100-form-radio m-t-15">
    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio1" type="radio" name="type-product[]" value="male" checked="checked">
    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio1">
      Male
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="contact100-form-radio">
    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio2" type="radio" name="type-product[]" value="female">
    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio2">
      Female
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to change the `id` of the radio button everytime this function is called.

There is no count to how many times the checkboxes will be dynamically created. I do not want a very complex code. Just something simple and easy to understand.

Comment: can you create fiddle?

Comment: _"i need to change the id of the radio button everytime this function is called"_ - Why?

Comment: Then you can create an id that is random and then append it the existing id. This can be done whenever the above function is called. Then the radio buttons will have the different id that can happen countless number of times, on every function load.

Comment: _"i need to change the id of the radio button everytime this function is called" - Why?_   since the id is the same, any  check to the newly created checkboxes alters the entry in the previous checkbox and does not actually give an entry to the current checkbox

Comment: _Then you can create an id that is random and then append it the existing id. This can be done whenever the above function is called. Then the radio buttons will have the different id that can happen countless number of times, on every function load._ can you give me the code

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar rather than copying the comment use "@" to reply to the specific person in comments :)

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar check out my answer and tell me if this is what you wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add some counter in js and use it as a number in `id`

```js
var count = 3;

$("#add_driver").click(function() {
  $("#add_driver_section").append("<div class='wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100' ><span class='label-input100'>Gender</span><div class='contact100-form-radio m-t-15'> <input class='input-radio100' id='radio" + count + "' type='radio' name='type-product[]' value='male' checked='checked' > <label class='label-radio100' for='radio" + count + "'> Male </label></div><div class='contact100-form-radio'> <input class='input-radio100' id='radio" + ++count + "' type='radio' name='type-product[]' value='female'> <label class='label-radio100' for='radio" + count + "'> Female </label> </div></div>");
  count++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
  <span class="label-input100">Gender</span>
  <div class="contact100-form-radio m-t-15">
    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio1" type="radio" name="type-product[]" value="male" checked="checked">
    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio1">
      Male
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="contact100-form-radio">
    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio2" type="radio" name="type-product[]" value="female">
    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio2">
      Female
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add_driver">Add driver</button>

<section id="add_driver_section"></section>
```

I hope this is what you want to achieve. If not, then let me know.

**EDIT**

If you want those radio buttons not to act as one radio set, then you need to give them different number.

**Here is an example**

```js
var count = 3;

$("#add_driver").click(function() {
  $("#add_driver_section").append("<div class='wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100' ><span class='label-input100'>Gender</span><div class='contact100-form-radio m-t-15'> <input class='input-radio100' id='male-radio" + count + "' type='radio' name='type-product-" + count + "[]' value='male' checked='checked' > <label class='label-radio100' for='male-radio" + count + "'> Male </label></div><div class='contact100-form-radio'> <input class='input-radio100' id='female-radio" + count + "' type='radio' name='type-product-" + count + "[]' value='female'> <label class='label-radio100' for='female-radio" + count + "'> Female </label> </div></div>");
  count++;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
  <span class="label-input100">Gender</span>
  <div class="contact100-form-radio m-t-15">
    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio1" type="radio" name="type-product[]" value="male" checked="checked">
    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio1">
      Male
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="contact100-form-radio">
    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio2" type="radio" name="type-product[]" value="female">
    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio2">
      Female
    </label>
  </div>
</div>

<button id="add_driver">Add driver</button>

<section id="add_driver_section"></section>
```

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar could you please be more specific? Because the code is working. It just appears that you wanted a different solution. Please describe what exactly would you  want to happen.

Comment: if you run the code you gave, you'll find out that after clicking the add button, the previous entry stops working. The problem with this code is that every time you click the add button the variable is set to 3

Comment: First of all it dos not stop working (you can click that). Secondly, what variable that sets to 3 are you referring to? As to first point, if you want those radiobuttons to be separate you need to give them uniqe name.

Comment: `var count = 3;`

Comment: Oh, no, you're not right. It starts with value 3 because value 1 and 2 you already have on page. But with every click it is increased. You can try clicking add button a couple of times and see that every next radio has unique id with number.

Comment: the edited code is what i want. but could you also tell me how to insert the data obtained from the checkboxes to mysqli

Comment: Now that is a completely different question. Please try to look for solution on your own and if you will fail then ask the question here. If my solution helped you, then do not forget to accept it (green chek mark)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var i = 0;
$("#add_driver").click(function() {
  i = i + 1;
  $("#add_driver_section").append("<div class='wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100' ><span class='label-input100'>Gender</span><div class='contact100-form-radio m-t-15'> <input class='input-radio100' id='male-radio"+i+"' type='radio' name='type-product-"+i+"[]' value='male' checked='checked' > <label class='label-radio100' for='male-radio"+i+"'> Male </label></div><div class='contact100-form-radio'> <input class='input-radio100' id='female-radio"+i+"' type='radio' name='type-product-"+i+"[]' value='female'> <label class='label-radio100' for='female-radio"+i+"'> Female </label> </div></div>");
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
  <span class="label-input100">Gender</span>
  <div class="contact100-form-radio m-t-15">
    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio1" type="radio" name="type-product[]" value="male" checked="checked">
    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio1">
      Male
    </label>
  </div>

  <div class="contact100-form-radio">
    <input class="input-radio100" id="radio2" type="radio" name="type-product[]" value="female">
    <label class="label-radio100" for="radio2">
      Female
    </label>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="add_driver_section"></div>
<button id="add_driver">Add</button>
```

Maybe you want something like this? You need to give unique name also to allow selection for each driver. Else it will update the previously selected radio button. Let me know if it works for you?

Comment: is there any other way by which i dont have to use the button

Comment: Which button ? @NEETHINNambiar