# number of times an event has occured

Tags: jquery, html

```
 $("#add_driver").click(function () {}
```

How do I find out how many times an event has occurred in the same page using jquery? Is there a simple way to do that?

Comment: You can count until the page is refreshed.

Comment: If the event is `click` event, then you can use an external counter like some of the answers given below, and if there is `each` or `forEach` event, then, `variable.each(function(i){...});`, here `i` gives you the counter. But as mentioned above, it can only be checked till the page is refreshed.

Comment: Can you share the HTML here, so that we can provide you the suitable fix.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50941620/9939706   its the same code as given in this question

Comment: "_$("#add_driver").click(function () {}_", I cannot find id `add_driver` anywhere in the code. Can you please update the basic code of the form, that you are working on?

Comment: `<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
<div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_driver">
<span> Add another Driver
<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</span>
</div>
</div>`

Comment: @NEETHINNambiar, check my answer, I think this is the one you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var count = 0;
 jQuery("#add_driver").click(function(){
 count++;
});
```

Use this code to take the count of button click.
To check the count make a 
 alert(count);
yes, sure you can store this value in session.

Comment: can i pass the value of count to the next page using session?

Answer (score 3):

Use a global variable `count` with `0` and increment that value inside the `click` function. If you also want to consider the page refresh then you need to store that value in `localStorage` and get that value on page load to maintain correct click count.

**NOTE**

Using `localStorage`, user may manually change the `count` value so it is also not a better way to use. You can use a API to call that when page refreshes to `get` and `set` the `count` value.

```js
var count = 0;

$("#add_driver").click(function () {
  count++;
  console.log('clicked count:', count);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='add_driver'>click me</div>
```

Comment: i have tried this but its not working. the deal is that it is a form and after the click event the user has to add more data after which again he can click.

Comment: how can i store the value of the counter to local storage?

Comment: You can google that out on saving data in `localStorage` @NEETHINNambiar

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I would add an example that didn't include jQuery.

```
var click = document.getElementById('button-click');

var count = 0;

click.onclick = function() {
    count++;
    console.log("Clicks counted " + count);
}
```

As for the HTML I just used a basic button for this example, but feel free to experiment as I have with the code below.

```
<button id="button-click">Nice</button>
```

Testing multiple clicks works

```
click.onclick = function() {
count++;
console.log("Clicks counted " + count);
 if (count === 2) {
     console.log("it works");
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the HTML provided by you, and the approach suggested by many above is working. I am attaching a snippet here with the answer, please check. I just added additional CSS, a bit out of context though, to make the div look like a button.

```js
var counter = 0;
$("#add_driver").click(function() {
  counter++;
  $("#counter").html(counter);
});
```

```css
#add_driver{
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap-input100 validate-input bg1 rs1-wrap-input100">
  <div class="contact100-form-btn" id="add_driver">
    <span> Add another Driver (Keep clicking me) <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right m-l-7" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div id = "counter"></div>
```

I just have added an additional `div` that displays the number of times the div was clicked, acting as a counter.

I hope it was helpful.

Comment: i just need the number in the end after all the clicks. imean just the total number of clicks.

Comment: So, the counter that is displayed below is the total number of the clicks till you do the next click, I have displayed it here, and you can just do whatever you want to do with it. In the end you will always have the total number of clicks.